# How to make multiple calls to SQLiteOpenHelper as a single atomic transaction?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, concurrency

I have an `SQLiteOpenHelper` class that implements the singleton pattern and has three methods: `addLogs()`, `getLogs()`, and `deleteLogs()`. Seven threads (triggered by a `BroadcastReceiver` at certain schedules) access the database--six of them only use `addLogs()`, and the other one uses `getLogs()` and calls `deleteLogs()` before it finishes.

My problem is, because the last thread makes two different calls to the SQLite database, the other threads can call on `addLogs()` even before `deleteLogs()` is called, which corrupts my output. How can I make that one thread treat the two calls to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a single, atomic transaction?

What I've tried: Create a static `ReentrantLock` member in the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and call `lock()` and `unlock()` from every one of the seven threads before and after their transactions. The other six threads still get through even though the last one still has the lock, which it calls before `getLogs()` and releases after `deleteLogs()`.

**UPDATE:** This is the seventh thread that accesses the two methods.

```
public class Uploader extends Thread {

    private Context context;

    public Uploader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Logger.d("STARTED: Uploader");
        DB db = DB.getInstance(context);
        List<JsonLog> logs = db.getLogs(); // FIRST CALL
        String json = new Gson().toJson(logs); // convert to JSON

        // connect to the server and upload
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(This.URL);
        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        try {
            Logger.d("to upload: " + json);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            post.setEntity(se);
            StatusLine status = client.execute(post).getStatusLine();
            // if upload is successful
            if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                db.deleteLogs(); // SECOND CALL
            } else {
                Logger.d("Uploader failed. " + status.getStatusCode() + ": " + status.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.d("FINISHED: Uploader");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite has transactions as in `db.beginTransaction()`, `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` to mark  the Tx to be committed and `db.endTransaction()` to finally mark the Tx as to be done.

So you could in your `getLogs()` do the `beginTransaction` and in the `deleteLogs` to mark it as done (and successful).

[Update] 
Now with your code snippet you probably would want to call `beginTransaction` before your 1st call and in a `finally` block, that adds to the `try-catch` block call into `endTransaction`. At the end of the `try` part if the status is ok, you would call `setTransactionSuccessful` (after the `delete` call.

Comment: Oh wow, that's cool. But is there anyway I can do something similar from the thread's `run()` method, though, and hence as an `SQLiteOpenHelper` object? I'm afraid I might add another thread that will make calls to `getLogs()` and `deleteLogs()` separately.

Comment: I updated my question to include the code for the seventh thread, which is `Uploader`. I'm hoping to call on something like `beginTransaction` before the first call, and `setTransactionSuccessful` and `endTransaction` after the whole upload process completes.